# Android libstagefright_h264 ff_get_buffer was not declared in this scope error

Tags: android, ffmpeg, stagefright

i am trying to built ffmpeg with decoder as `libstagefright_h264`, slightly modified the given script in ffmpeg to point to android source in local file system. When make, i get

```
ff_get_buffer was not declared in this scope
```

error. What is causing this? How to get around it?

Answer (score 0):

Update your ffmpeg source. libstagefright.cpp was broken and didn't have the correct include for "internal.h" at one point.

https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/commit/dda8afc391798e345c73f857f8e0fb8424ceb77b